# "-2 days" in the "you have reached the question limit" page

Tags: bug, status-completed

Quoting a small part from the "you reached the question limit" page which appears when I press the <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button:

> It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait -2 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.

Now how much time am I supposed to wait until I can ask another question? -2 days?!?

EDIT: After one day,the message changed to

> It's been 1 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 2 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.

Comment: This *is* Puzzling.SE.

Comment: @AE ,So,Is that is a Puzzle? Hmmmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build - details here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274841/im-banned-from-asking-questions-for-negative-days/281874#281874

Comment: Will [this](http://www.meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/1-days-should-be-1-day-in-the-you-reached-your-question-limit-page) be fixed too?

Comment: It's, uh, *on a list.*